# Search Kit: Network Error issue when we use any query with Group By that gives results and then try to select "This Page"

Tags: searchkit

Steps to reproduce:

1. Select some filters (Addresses, Address Contact, Contact Type, Address Location, Contact Source) and grouped by 'Created Date"
2. Click the checkbox at the header which selects "This Page" - notice at the bottom of the page only 1 of 40 results were selected even though all contacts on the page had checkmarks
3. Click "Action" -> "Export Contacts"
4. Network Error with "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again." message appears

Even when "All Pages" checkbox at the header is clicked and if any row has multiple contacts then only first contact of that row is getting exported.[image]

Comment: Have you tried to replicate on a very simple search kit search to see if the export/download is actually working?

Comment: @GuillaumeSorel When I perform a simple search without "Group By" export/download is working fine but with "Group By" after selecting "This Page" sometimes even "All Pages" comes up with network error.

Comment: so I guess it's the beginning of a solution